# Bootstrap Slider - Update value on slide OR click

Tags: javascript, slider, bootstrap-slider

I am using a bootstrap slider on my site using HTML and JavaScript (no Jquery). It is set up pretty much as I want it, with permanent tooltips and values etc.

However, I want to store the value that the user finishes on. I have this working to some extent, IF the user slides the slider. If the user CLICKS on the slider then it doesn't update the value.

Any advice on tracking any kind of interaction?

HTML:

```
<input id="sliderman1" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="4" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="2" data-slider-ticks="[0, 4]"/> 
<span id="sliderman1Value">3</span></span>
```

JS:

```
var values = ['None', 'Read', 'Speak', 'Test', 'Last'];
var formatter = (index) => values[index];

var slider = new Slider("#sliderman1", {formatter} );
slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue) {
document.getElementById("sliderman1Value").textContent = sliderValue;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an onTouchEnd event listener?

JS

```
slider.on("onTouchEnd", function(sliderValue) {
   document.getElementById("sliderman1Value").textContent = sliderValue;
}
```

or add it directly to your slider:
HTML

```
<input ontouchend="myFunction(event)" ... />
```